# Define Interface for function, for which I do not have access to the declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

Is there a way to define which arguments and which types of arguments a function argument takes. For example:

[image]

I would like to use TypeScript to declare what the interface is for the `boundTransportFn`. The type of that argument is a function, but how can I use TypeScript to define what arguments that function takes?

***Important: This function (boundTransportFn) is a user provided function that I don't have access to. In other words, I do not have access to the boundTransportFn declaration, all I have is the parameter***

Comment: I believe most downvotes were given because you are including your code as a screenshot, which is frowned upon. Indeed, why would you _ever_ choose to include a _picture_ of your code, instead of the code _itself_? Remember, you are asking for help, and people will help you for _free_: you should make it as easy for them to help you as possible. Nobody will bother with typing down your code by hand to verify the problem, when it could be simply copy-pasted instead. StackOverflow has code-formatting and syntax-highlighting functions. The question's content is fine, IMO.

Comment: then a downvoter should mention that; thanks for the feedback; I still don't think I have a good answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question properly, but here's how you can declare an argument that is a function taking two arguments - `any` and `string` - and returning `void` (that's what I think the type of the function should be when I look at your code):

```
return function (boundTransportFn: (a: any, key: string) => void) {
}
```

See also "Writing the function type" section in the [handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is:

```js
interface SearchFunc {
    (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
}

let mySearch: SearchFunc;
mySearch = function(source: string, subString: string) {
    let result = source.search(subString);
    return result > -1;
}
```

Note that this is coming straight from the [official Typescript handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types). ;-)

So, to follow your example:

```js
interface BoundFunc {
  // Put your definition here
}

// Then, somewhere else:
export class MyClass {

  myMethod(boundTransportFn: BoundFunc) {
    return function(boundTransportFn) {
      // ...
    }
  }

}
```

Users of `MyClass.myMethod()` must comply with the `BoundFunc` interface.

Comment: However, are you sure this works for the situation I described in the question? This function (boundTransportFn) is a user provided function that I don't have access to. In other words, I do not have access to the boundTransportFn declaration, all I have is the parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Adding a type to the `boundTransportFn` function in YOUR code is only a matter of replacing the word `Function` by the name of the interface you declared in YOUR code. You don't provide much context for your piece of code, but assuming it is located within a method that receives `boundTransportFn` as a parameter, any user calling your method would have to provide correctly-typed parameters or the TypeScript compiler would complain. Makes sense?

Comment: I will keep the upvote here but I believe the other answer is the one I am looking for